# Image send by discord bot won't load

Tags: javascript, discord.js

If i execute this, it will send an image but won't load the image.

```
}else if(command == 'image'){
    const attachment1 = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./C99paVv.jpg');
    message.channel.send( {
        files: [{
            attachment: 'https://i.imgur.com/0Xz0shI.png', 
            name: 'C99paVv.png'
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: Does your bot have permission to post images?

Comment: Yes, it has all permissions needed.

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Open in Browser" on the image to see if it is your fault or if the discord proxy isn't working?